# Trying to reuse a path to an object in xaml

Tags: xaml, path

I have several items in a xaml file that I want to bind to different objects. I show an example with two buttons:

```
<Button Content="Edit Operators" 
Command="{Binding ElementName=treeRevisions,
Path=SelectedItem.WorkOrderRev.Operators.EditCommand}" CommandParameter="" />
<Button Content="Edit MyData" 
Command="{Binding ElementName=treeRevisions,
Path=SelectedItem.WorkOrderRev.MyData.EditCommand}" CommandParameter="" />
```

As you can see, the text **"Binding ElementName=treeRevisions, Path=SelectedItem.WorkOrderRev"** is the same for both buttons. It works and I could use it like this, but I have lots of other controls also. Is there some way I could shorten this and just append the **".Operators.EditCommand"** etc? I have looked everywhere for a solution but I haven't found anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. I ll post you an very tricky one.
Warning this is a crazy answer for wpf pro but it works. Hahaha...

```
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new { D = "Hello" };
        }

        public static bool GetDoMyBinding(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(DoMyBindingProperty);
        }

        public static void SetDoMyBinding(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(DoMyBindingProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for DoMyBinding.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DoMyBindingProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("DoMyBinding", typeof(bool),  typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnDoMyBindingChanged)));

        private static void OnDoMyBindingChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Binding binding = new Binding("D");
            binding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
            if (d is Button)
            {
                Button b = d as Button;
                b.SetBinding(Button.ContentProperty, binding);
            }
            if (d is TextBlock)
            {
                TextBlock tb = d as TextBlock;
                tb.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, binding);
            }
        }
```

Your XAML would look like this:

```
    <Window x:Class="BindingTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BindingTest">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button local:MainWindow.DoMyBinding="True"/>
        <Button  local:MainWindow.DoMyBinding="True"/>
        <TextBlock  local:MainWindow.DoMyBinding="True" />
    </StackPanel>
    </Window>
```

Result would be like this:

[image]

Edited: Instead True, you can place your custom string such as ".Operators.EditCommand" but then you would need to change the logic.

Have fun.

Comment: Thanks! I will have a look at this. Although I will use my own solution below.

Answer (score 0):

I tested some different solutions and found a very simple one.
I set the DataContext on the surrounding Grid like this:

```
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=treeRevisions, Path=SelectedItem.WorkOrderRev.PrintData}">
```

Then I can use abbrevations like this:

```
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="103,63,0,0" Name="txtDescription" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" 
     IsEnabled="{Binding Path=UnLocked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}"
     IsReadOnly="{Binding Path=Locked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}"
     Text="{Binding Path=TableData.Rows[0][description], UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
     />
```

where Locked, UnLocked and TableData are properties of SelectedItem.WorkOrderRev.PrintData.